# Passing map as an argument using boost :: bind

Tags: c++, string, class, dictionary, compiler-errors

I need to pass in the index of a `map` which is a `std::wstring` and its value which is also a `std::wstring`, to a member function which takes 3 `std::wstrings` as arguments.
I am trying to use the `boost::bind` in the `write` method in `class Result` as shown in the example code below..

I am re-posting the code with more clarity, and am getting compile errors.

```
    typedef std::map<std::wstring,std::wstring> map_type;

    class Print
    {
    public:
       Print(){};
       virtual ~Print(){};
       void setValue(const std::wstring & str1, const std::wstring & str2,
                const std::wstring & str3 = L"")
       {
          wprintf(L"String1[%ls] String2[%ls] String3[%ls]\n",str1.c_str(), str2.c_str(), str3.c_str());
       }
    };

    class Result : public Print
    {
       public:
       Result(){};
       virtual ~Result(){};
       void write(const std::wstring val1, const std::wstring val2, const std::wstring val3)
       {      
          std::map<std::wstring,std::wstring> my_map_test;
          my_map_test[L"Idx1"]=L"Value1";
          my_map_test[L"Idx2"]=L"Value2";         

          for_each(my_map_test.begin(), my_map_test.end(),
          boost::bind(&Result::setValue,
             boost::bind(&map_type::value_type::first,_1),
             boost::bind(&map_type::value_type::second,_1), L"TEST"));
       }
    };

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   Result result;
   result.write();
   return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Clearly that's not real code since your parenthesis are mismatched and you can't construct a `std::string` from a wide string literal. What is your _real_ code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `typedef` isn't quite right. Other than that it seems that you are missing a parenthesis after each of your nested `bind()` expressions. It seems, `Data::setValue` is a member function, i.e., it also needs to be given the object it is to be applied on. That is, I think you want to use it like this:

```
std::for_each(mem_ptr->properties.m_properties_map.begin(),
              mem_ptr->properties.m_properties_map.end(), 
              boost::bind(&Data::setValue,
                          boost::ref(object), 
                          boost::bind(&map_type::value_type::first, _1),
                          boost::bind(&map_type::value_type::second, _1),
                          L"Str"));
```

˙
Sadly, I can't test that this would, indeed, work because you only provided partial code. Otherwise it is an interesting idea to expand the pair using composition. Note, that `first` and `second` are also members (of `std::pair<K, V>`) but these member can be "called" using just one parameter, namely the object on which they are called. For data members `bind()` pretends that they can be called to access the value correspondingly

Comment: Ok. I found the problem, the issue seems to be related to the &Data::setValue member function call. If i pull the setValue fn out of the Data object, and call like boost::bind(&setValue...... then it works. I don't know why calling a member fn which is inside an obj is causing an issue. Is there a different syntax ? Any ideas...?

Comment: Yes, this as well. Sorry, I didn't spot this but if `setValue()` is a non-static member function it takes and additional argument for the object on which the member function is called. I obviously got distracted by your mismatched parenthesis and wrong typedef.

Comment: The typedef is fine. In my original post the parenthesis were mismatched, but i fixed it and it was still causing an issue.What is the syntax for using the setValue as a member function within the Data object in boost::bind?

Comment: The declaration `typedef <std::string, std::string> map_type;` is certainly **not** fine (it is lacking something like `std::map`) and when I wrote my response the parenthesis were mismatch. With respect to using a member function point, the syntax is the same but the function would use 4 instead of 3 arguments: The first argument is the object you want the function to be called, probably a pointer or a reference to it. That is, it would look something like `boost::bind(&Data::setValue, boost::ref(object), ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

After testing it again, it works now, the only parameter that was missing while using boost::bind was the the "this" pointer as shown below

for_all(my_map_test, 
         boost::bind(&Result::setValue, **this**,
         boost::bind(&map_type::value_type::first,_1),
         boost::bind(&map_type::value_type::second,_1), L"TEST"));